# Vue custom Directive - object properties undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, directive

I have a custom Vue directive to show/hide an element based on a role.

```
Vue.directive('role', (el, binding, vnode ) => {
  const modifiers = binding.modifiers
  const roles = vnode.context.$store.state.roles;

  if (!roles.includes(binding.value) ||  (roles.includes(binding.value) && modifiers.not)) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    vnode.elm.parentElement.removeChild(vnode.elm)

  }
})
```

This is the template and is in a v-for. They don't exist for admin users, I have

```
  <span
    v-role="'admin'"
  >
     {{ user.firstName }}, {{ user.lastName  }}
  </span>
```

The issue I am having is either using displaying none or removing the child still throws the error

**Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined**

I can do a check for the property in the template but is there a way just not to render it if it does not exist?

Comment: you can simply use `v-if` as display:none will render it and apply the css.

Comment: I don't want to use v-if

Comment: Could you please post a workable demo in codepen or sandbox, that helps to get your problem clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add safeguards:

```html
  <span v-role="'admin'">
     {{ (user || {}).firstName }}, {{ (user || {}).lastName  }}
  </span>
```